# Find all objects in database where 5th level value equals specific criteria

Tags: mongodb

I have objects such as this in Mongo database:

```
 {{{}{}}{}}{}{{}{{{}}}
```

I am not sure how would a query look like to find all objects that match next criteria:

Find all objects where `messages[i].payload.headers.name[7].value == aa@aa.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears it is not necessary to use indexes for arrays. The query object I was looking for looks like this:

```
{"messages.payload.headers.value":"foo@example.com"}
```